# Functional style in Scala to collect results from a method

Tags: scala, collections

I have two lists that I zip and go through the zipped result and call a function. This function returns a List of Strings as response. I now want to collect all the responses that I get and I do not want to have some sort of buffer that would collect the responses for each iteration.

```
seq1.zip(seq2).foreach((x: (Obj1, Obj1)) => {
  callMethod(x._1, x._2) // This method returns a Seq of String when called
}
```

What I want to avoid is to create a ListBuffer and keep collecting it. Any clues to do it functionally?

Comment: Just use `.map` instead of `.foreach`. Or you could even use `.flatMap` to flatten your `List[Seq[String]]` to `List[String]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use [map()](http://www.brunton-spall.co.uk/post/2011/12/02/map-map-and-flatmap-in-scala/) to transform each input into a corresponding output ? Here's `map()` operating in a simple scenario:

```
scala> val l = List(1,2,3,4,5)
scala> l.map( x => x*2 )
res60: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
```

so in your case it would look something like:

```
seq1.zip(seq2).map((x: (Obj1, Obj1)) => callMethod(x._1, x._2))
```

Given that your function returns a Seq of Strings, you *could* use `flatMap()` to flatten the results into one sequence.